# Making a faster wavelet transform/Appending data faster

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, pywt

I am taking 1-D wavelet transform of  data. How can I make this faster?
I have 1.4 million samples and 32 features.

```
def apply_wavelet_transform(data):
    ca,cd=pywt.dwt(data[0,:],'haar')
    for i in range(1,data.shape[0]):
        ca_i,__=pywt.dwt(data[i,:],'haar')
        ca=np.vstack((ca,ca_i))
    return ca
```

Consider I don't care about memory usage as much as speed of execution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a common mistake. You don't want to append rows to an array one at a time, because each iteration requires copying the entire array. Complexity: O(N**2). Much better to keep the intermediate results in a list and form the array at the end. This is better because lists do not require their elements to be contiguous in memory, so no copying is required.

```
def apply_wavelet_transform(data):
    results_list = []
    for row in data:
        ca, cd = pywt.dwt(row, 'haar')
        results_list.append(ca)
    result = np.array(results_list)
    return result
```

Comment: Or as a one-liner (more concise, less readable, same performance): result = np.array([pywt.dwt(row, 'haar')[0] for row in data])

Comment: What's the use of `[0]`?

Comment: [0] selects the first element of the returned tuple (ca, cd) from pywt.dwt